# Hide information in the blockchain

Tags: smart-contract, blockchains

Lets say I want to create a player vs player game with a battlefield and moving armies, the movement and data about the armies and where is it going is put on the blockchain.
My question is how to prevent a player from seeing from afar when he is gonna get attacked and by what and whom ?